# how to reenter normal mode after startinsert

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode

I met a weird problem: Vim is still in insert mode after executing the code below, it's weird because the redraw command did work.

```
:startinsert
execute 'silent !ls'
execute 'normal "\<esc>"'
:redraw!
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
:call feedkeys("\<esc>")
```